# Firebase realtime showing (other) for location and app version

Tags: android, firebase

I'm not sure if I made a mistake in implementing firebase in my app, but I see a lot of (other) in the Locations and App Versions as can be seen in the screenshots below:
[image]
[image]

If I filter by either Location or App Version, everything else shows as (other) like Events for example... I'm not sure if this is an implementation issue or what.

Has anybody experienced this? Is there a way to fix it?